# Is there a reason to load a temp table with data, then select from it in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm reviewing some stored procedures in a 3rd party app my employer has purchased.  They whole system runs slow as molasses.

Every single select stored procedure has the most convoluted select I've ever seen.  And practically EVERY stored procedure is written this way.  (StackOverflow needs a WTF hash tag too.)

Before I gut these and make appropriate changes to the code, has anyone ever seen stored procedures coded this way?

Code works, but it seems like it there are 20 better ways to do it.  Using Linq in code to sort the data set for one.  Making just one call to the DB, and putting the (smallish) result set in a session variable.

```
create PROCEDURE dbo.sp_REALLYWEIRD
(
   @parameter1 varchar(5), @parameter2 varchar(5), @parameter3 varchar(5), 
   @sortField varchar(20), @sortDirection  int, @OrgIdentifier varchar(5),
   @startRowIndex int,  @maximumRows int, @rowCount int OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN

   DECLARE @returnValue TABLE (
          Id            int           NOT NULL,
          SomeColumn1   char(7)       NOT NULL,
          SomeColumn2   datetime      NULL,
          SomeColumn3   datetime      NULL,
          SomeColumn4   varchar(18)   NOT NULL,
          SomeColumn5   smallint      NOT NULL,
          RowNumber     int           NOT NULL)

   DECLARE   @endRowIndex int
   SET   @endRowIndex = @startRowIndex + @maximumRows

   IF @sortField IS NULL
      SET @sortField = 'SomeColumnName'

   INSERT INTO   @returnValue
         (Id, SomeColumn1, SomeColumn2, SomeColumn3,
         SomeColumn4, SomeColumn5, RowNumber)
      SELECT Id, SomeColumn1, SomeColumn2, SomeColumn3,
             SomeColumn4, SomeColumn5, RowNumber
        FROM (SELECT Id,SomeColumn1, SomeColumn2, SomeColumn3,
                     SomeColumn4, SomeColumn5,
                     CASE @sortField 
                        WHEN 'SomeColumnName1' THEN
                           CASE @sortDirection
                              WHEN 1 THEN Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY DistrictLea ORDER BY SomeColumn1) - 1
                              ELSE Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY DistrictLea ORDER BY SomeColumn1 DESC) - 1
                        END
                        WHEN 'SomeColumnName2' THEN
                           CASE @sortDirection
                              WHEN 1 THEN Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY DistrictLea ORDER BY SomeColumn2) - 1
                              ELSE Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY DistrictLea ORDER BY SomeColumn2 DESC) - 1
                        END                              
                        WHEN 'SomeColumnName3' THEN
                           CASE @sortDirection
                              WHEN 1 THEN Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY DistrictLea ORDER BY SomeColumn3) - 1
                              ELSE Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY DistrictLea ORDER BY SomeColumn3 DESC) - 1
                        END
                        WHEN 'SomeColumnName4' THEN
                           CASE @sortDirection
                              WHEN 1 THEN Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY DistrictLea ORDER BY SomeColumn4) - 1
                              ELSE Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY DistrictLea ORDER BY SomeColumn4 DESC) - 1
                        END
                     END AS RowNumber
               FROM  dbo.someTable
               WHERE OrgIdentifier = @OrgIdentifier) t

   SELECT @rowCount = COUNT(*)
     FROM @returnValue

   SELECT Id, SomeColumn1, SomeColumn2, SomeColumn3,
          SomeColumn4, SomeColumn5
     FROM @returnValue
    WHERE RowNumber >= @startRowIndex
      AND RowNumber < @endRowIndex
    ORDER BY RowNumber
END
```

Seems like a lot of work just to load a data grid.

Comment: looks like a sorted paged data set.. so a little more than just a data grid..

Comment: "Using Linq in code to sort the data set for one" not a guarantee that it would be better, particularly for large datasets. And as Randy said, the table variable is used to calculate the total rows and to page the results. Do you really want to retrieve ALL the result set to linq when you just need a page? What happens if you have 100k rows and pages of 20?

Comment: But we're not talking tens of thousands of records.  Everything could be handled in code with out multiple calls to the DB.

Comment: Like I said, this is a pretty small data set we're talking about.  It's like this is the template, and they used it for every call regardless.  In this case, 41 records.

Comment: You may find some better techniques in [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html). Aside: `SELECT @rowCount = COUNT(*) FROM @returnValue`? How about `set @rowCount = @@RowCount;`?

Comment: I find it tough to call this a question. seems more like a request for code review :) Randy has pretty much answered it. How many records means little. If the file is loaded (from a file?) just so this proc can sort it... then that seems reasonable. It'd be tougher to load the file directly to whatever presentation tech is being used and/or to sort a text file. As for the efficiency or prettiness of the code... haven't even considered that. This isn't the place for a code review imho.

Comment: There really isn't a question here. Yes I have seen this done before but the performance is going to be horrible.

Comment: You should post this in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and as for the temp tables you should research the difference between memory temp tables @ disk temp table # common table expressions and consider to use sub-queries. And also, how your indexes are of no benefit after such approach.

Comment: ah cool! there is a place for code reviews! There you have it ARLib - that should work perfect for you.

Comment: Thanks for the code review website.  I've not seen that one before.  Thanks!

Comment: To answer your question, there are plenty of reasons one might want to load a temp table before selecting out of the proc. Many of those reasons would be quite valid. Many others are just plain stupid. And then sometimes, there are situations where performance is going to suck, but there may be a need. I don't think your scenario practices the best approach.

Comment: FOR THE RECORD, NOT MY CODE.  Custom built 3rd party app.  In 15+ years of SQL I've never written a query this way.  Yes, there are times I've need to use variable tables to store data while it was being manipulated, even the occasional temp table, but nothing like this.  I'm also finding this vendor liked to use select splat in a lot of places.  Even when he only needed a couple of fields from a table.